# How do you color specific letters in emacs?

Tags: emacs, elisp

In a new and hopefully very simple emacs mode I would like every instance of 'a' to be #0000FF and 'b' to be #DF0101. Thus far I haven't found a way to do this despite lots of googling. Ideally it would happen in realtime, as you typed.

http://www.gnu.org/savannah-checkouts/gnu/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Highlight-Interactively.html

http://www.gnu.org/savannah-checkouts/gnu/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Font-Lock.html#Font-Lock

Comment: I'm just curious but any specific reason to do this?

Comment: There is a good reason.. this is a boiled down example. I will post the final mode if the question is answered, thanks!

Comment: If you know elisp why not add a hook for keypresses and simply setting the color of the current character when it matches?

Comment: I think you are suggesting turning 'a' into a command to 'insert a blue a', which maybe I can figure out. I'll report back, thanks.

Comment: The problem with binding `a` to `insert-blue-a` is that `a` will not be blue when you open the file, only when you insert a new one

Comment: tada (global-set-key (kbd "b") '(lambda () (interactive)(insert (propertize "b" 'font-lock-face '(:foreground "blue"))))) - brb with the rest :-)

Comment: I'm going to guess that you guys didn't see this coming..
https://github.com/brianmingus/synaesthesia-mode.el

@JesusRamos, if you put your comment as an answer I'll accept it. Thanks all!

Comment: I would use @Dualinity's answer to make it more flexible since you can use keywords. I tried out your elisp O_O if you wanted to make stuff impossible to read you succeeded :P

Comment: Haha, yea I think it is not easy to read, but I do think it contains the vital information. I would definetely like to mess around with creating all those seperate functions, but this or Stefan's methods are more efficient I believe.

Answer (score 5):

I use this for my Navi minor mode:

```
;; Adding Navi to the syntax highlighting of emacs mode.
```

First to make new faces, with their colors, in my case green for the success font for letter "t", and cyan for "Navi" and "navi".

If needed, read about [font-lock](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Font-Lock.html).

```
(make-face 'font-lock-Navi-face)
(set-face-foreground 'font-lock-Navi-face "cyan")

(make-face 'font-lock-success-face)
(set-face-attribute 'font-lock-success-face nil :foreground "green")
```

Now to add the 'keywords' ([regexp](https://www.google.nl/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&ved=0CDEQFjAA&url=http://emacswiki.org/emacs/RegularExpression&ei=C6wBUajhFM3B0gX96ICgDQ&usg=AFQjCNHx2-NZoAFnTO98yPQd9RWNOPbybQ&bvm=bv.41524429,d.d2k)) to which to attach:

```
(defun add-custom-keywords()
  "adds a few keywords for emacs mode"
  ;
  (font-lock-add-keywords nil
                     '(
                       ("Navi\\|navi" . 'font-lock-Navi-face)

 ;; here you can see that I highlight the letter "t" in " t " when spaced, 
 ;; or with a parenthesis\newline around it

                       ("\\s-t\\s-\\|\\s-t)\\|\\s-t\n" . 'font-lock-success-face)
                       )
                     )
)
```

You can replace Navi ("or" is here `"\\|"`) or navi with simply your letter, "a" or "b", so `"a\\|b"` and then give the face to it.

```
; This is the hook to activate when the mode is triggered
(add-hook 'emacs-lisp-mode-hook 'add-custom-keywords)
```

The last part ensures that this font will be "real-time", and every time you open the file.

Answer (score 4):

`add-font-lock-keywords` is for user customizations, mostly.  If you're writing the mode yourself, it's much better to just set `font-lock-defaults` with an appropriate value.

Check `sample-mode` on the emacswiki for some example.

Comment: Yea I have to agree with you. I thought that this would give more flexibility, but even if font-locks are defined in the minor-mode, that does not impede you from making changes later. You got my vote.

Comment: Actually, now that you mention it, `add-font-lock-keywords` is also warranted for *minor* modes, indeed.